# Pass params to select query success call back in phoengap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

How can I pass additional params to success callback for this phone gap transaction? Here is the code:

```
 db.transaction(function (transaction) {
    var sql = 'SELECT SYNC_DATE_TIME FROM SYNC_HISTORY WHERE SYNC_NAME=?'
    transaction.executeSql(sql, [syncName],getSycDateQuerySuccessCB, errorCB);
}, getLastSyncDateErrorCB, getLastSyncDateSuccessCB)
```

I wanted to pass `syncName` var to `getSycDateQuerySuccessCB`. Call back function variable comes into this function as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the framework doesn't provide additional variables to the callback function, you won't be able have those passed into your function.  Your best bet is to pass a closure that calls your other callback:

```
db.transaction(function (transaction) 
    {
        var sql = 'SELECT SYNC_DATE_TIME FROM SYNC_HISTORY WHERE SYNC_NAME=?'
        transaction.executeSql(
                sql,
                [syncName],
                function(resultSet) { getSycDateQuerySuccessCB(resultSet, syncName); }, 
                errorCB
        );
    }, getLastSyncDateErrorCB, getLastSyncDateSuccessCB
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,if we pass like so does getSycDateQuerySuccessCB(syncName) function takes result variable as returned from select query?

Comment: Check out the docs for the `executeSql` function. When doing a `SELECT` statement, the callback is called with a `SQLResultSet` object as defined here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSet.  Check out the edits to my answer to see how you can account for this.